# Underlined text in iPhone TextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, sqlite, xcode4.2

I have the following text in my RTF file..

"The possibility of an attack on Indian Point, a nuclear power plant, has caused local governmental officials to plan evaluation routes, build shelters, and offering citizens potassium pills so there will be fewer casualties in case of a leak."

In that text "plan evaluation routes, build shelters, and offering citizens potassium pills so there will be" is underlined text. When I am copying this text into sqlite database and displaying on Simulator using TextView, I am Not Getting UnderLine... How to get it in iPhone..? From Which Format (word,pdf..) of documents i want to copy to get the exact text...

Answer (score 0):

UITextView does not support any text attributes. You could use a UIWebview with some html to do that (the easy way) or write your own text field using Coretext and NSAttributedString. This site has quite some info about the later: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text

Answer (score 0):

TextView does not support underline text because its have single font behavior and does not support multiFont and text attributes. You can use web view inside text view for RTF File.
Try this link,it have lot of HTMl,which is easily understand.
http://kiefermat.com/2011/09/30/using-uiwebview-for-displaying-rich-text/